httpd and nfsd can not read usb external storage
Mac mini m4, macOS Sequoia
apache httpd webdav
nfs
Both httpd and nfsd work well when I share a directory on internal storage like /Users/abc/share.
When I share a directory on usb external storage like /Volumes/udisk/share, both httpd and nfsd raised errors like "can not read /Volumes/udisk/share" and "not permitted".
The exteranl storage file system is APFS. The owner user:group of /Volumes/udisk/share is abc:staff, the same as /Users/abc/share, and file mode is 777. The only difference is internal/external storage.
Does accessing external storage require additional authorization?
How can I resolve this issue? Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

It occurred to me that the system would pop up a window asking if permission was granted when certain applications were running. So I went to the security and privacy settings menu to check and found that smbd was granted full disk access permission. After adding this permission to httpd and nfsd, the problem was completely solved.

Excellent post and reminder to check headless daemons that can’t tell you they need permissions.
